# Телеграм бот и хостинг серверов

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, vps

Суммируется ли, производительность если закинуть тг бот, на несколько хостинг серверов?

Comment: Зависит от того, сможете ли вы спроектировать бота так, чтобы он эффективно распределял вычисления на эти несколько серверов; если сможете, то поможет. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что скорее всего вы даже производительность одного сервера используете не на всю катушку и думать о нескольких серверах вам ещё рано

Answer (score 0):

Ну если вы тупо попытаетесь код бота запустить на нескольких серверах, то телега вас пошлёт, так как телега не будет знать какой инстанс должен ответить.
Можно создать одного бота, который имеет хэндлеры для ответа на сообщения, а сложные процедуры(например там обработка картинок) будут пересылаться на другой сервер, тем самым уменьшая нагрузку на основной сервер, что положительно скажется на производительности. Распределение нагрузки это отдельная тема.